# Arithmetical hierarchy: Why is $\Delta_0^0\ne \Delta_1^0$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The definitions are different from one textbook to the other, but if we take the following definitions:

$\Delta_0^0$ = all the first-order arithmetic formulas with bounded quantifiers only.

$\Delta_1^0$ = conjunction of $\Sigma_1^0$ and $\Pi_1^0$.

Then it turns out $\Delta_0^0$ is strictly included in $\Delta_1^0$.

How does one proves they are different?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130432/is-delta-0-delta-1-in-arithmetical-hierarchy?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no $\Delta^0_1$ *formulas*, but there are $\Delta^0_1$ *sets of integers*, defined as the ones that are both definable by a $\Pi^0_1$ formula and definable by a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula.

The $\Delta^0_1$ sets are exactly the decidable sets (if there is a TM that always either halts-and-reject or halts-and-accepts, then "there is a computation that accepts" is the same as "every computation *doesn't reject*"; conversely a$\Delta^0_1$ set can be decided simply by looking in parallel for an example of the $\Sigma^0_1$ formula or a counterexample to the $\Pi^0_1$ formula).

On the other hand, not all decidable sets are $\Delta^0_0$. One argument for this is that any fixed $\Delta^0_0$ formula can be evaluated in time polynomial in the values of its free variables, and there are decidable sets that are not decidable within such a time bound, due to the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).

**Edit:** As a different approach, we can construct a concrete decidable set that is not $\Delta^0_0$ by direct diagonalization: Let $\varphi_0, \varphi_1, \varphi_2, \ldots$ be an effective enumeration of all $\Delta^0_0$ formulas. Then it is decidable whether $\varphi_n(m)$ is true or not, given $n$ and $m$. Now let
$$ A = \{n\in\mathbb N\mid \neg\varphi_n(n)\} $$
$A$ is obviously decidable, but it cannot be the extension of $\varphi_i$ for any $i$, because such an $i$ would be in $A$ if and only it isn't.

Comment: @Dani: When I write $\Delta_0^0$ it is because $\Delta^0_0$ is what I mean: The set of arithmical formulae where every quantification is bounded. What do you mean by "factorization of $n$ is in $\Delta^0_0$"? Factorization, as I understand it, is a problem of _actually displaying the factors_, and the value of a $\Delta^0_0$ formula is just either "true" or "false", never a number that can be a factor of your $n$.

Comment: I'm saying that for every $\Delta^0_0$ formula $\varphi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ there is a Turing machine that computes the truth value of $\varphi(n_1,\ldots,n_n)$ in time bounded by a fixed polynomial in the $n_i$s. This polynomial depends on which formula $\varphi$ is, but not on the value of the $n_i$s.

Comment: I believe you are referring to $\Delta_0^P$ of the polynomial hierarchy, rather than to the arithmetical hierarchy, which was what I was asking about. I also guess you mean "evaluated in polynomial time in the number of bits of the formula". Anyway, this is not the same as far as I understand.

For example, primality is in $\Delta_0^0$: the set of primes is the same as the numbers satisfying the following first-order arithmetic with no unbounded quantifiers:

$Prime(n) = \exists k<n: \exists m < n : k*m = n$

However, it was not known to be polynomial (= in $\Delta_0^P$) until 2002.

Comment: @Dani, what was proved in 2002 was that the primality of a number $n$ can be decided in time polynomial in $\log n$. On the other hand, it is easy to determine whether $n$ is prime in time polynomial in $n$ itself.

Comment: You're right, I was still referring to my thought that you meant polynomial in the number of bits (i.e. log n).

Comment: @Dani: I have edited the answer to give a different argument that doesn't involve polynomial times. Perhaps that is less likely to confuse.

Comment: Thanks, both arguments are convincing.

Is every set that is decidable in polynomial time in the values of its free variables in $\Delta_0^0$?

Comment: @Dani: I don't think so. It was just the first nontrivial upper bound on the class of $\Delta^0_0$ sets that came to mind for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41280/discussion-between-dani-and-henning-makholm).