# Understanding the Arithmetical Hierarchy

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

I am trying to get acquainted with the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy), and as I wrote down some examples, I got a bit confused.

Consider the language $L=\{+\cdot,<,=,0,1\}$ of $\mathsf{PA}$.

For example, the sentence $\phi:=\forall x\,\exists y\,(y<x\wedge x=y+1)$ is a $\Pi_{1}$-sentence because it is of the form $\forall x\,\theta$, where $\theta = \exists y\,(y<x\wedge x=y+1)$ is a formula having only bounded quantifiers.

On the other hand, in the sentence $\psi:=\forall x\,\exists y\,(x=y+1)$, the formula $(x=y+1)$ has no bounded quantifiers. Hence, what type of formula is $\psi$? How are formulas with no bounded quantifiers classified? In this case, $\theta$ and $\exists y\,(x=y+1)$ are logically equivalent.

What about the sentence $\forall x\,(x=x)$? Is it $\Pi_{0}$? If so, what about $(x=x)$?

A final example: [Goodstein's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) (where the sequence is defined recursively starting with $x$ in hereditary base $2$, bumping the base by $1$ and subtracting $1$ from the result) can be expressed as the sentence $G:=\forall x\,\exists y\,(g_{y}(x) = 0)$, where $g_{y}(x)$ denotes the $y^{th}$ term of the Goodstein sequence starting at $x$. I have read that $G$ is a $\Pi_{2}$-sentence. But the formula $(g_{y}(x) = 0)$ does not have bounded quantifiers. Is it equivalent to a formula having only bounded quantifiers?

These examples describe the nature of my confusion. Any guidance will be appreciated.

---

Edit: As far as I can tell now, there are several approaches to defining the arithmetic hierarchy. At least three. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1130463/30229) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830628/precise-definition-of-sigma-00-in-the-arithmetical-hierarchy?rq=1) do a good job of exhibiting different approaches and hashing out the details and how they may be linked (e.g. [Post's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem)). Differences occur at the bottom level $\Sigma_{0}=\Pi_{0}=\Delta_{0}$. But crucially all approaches agree as one moves up the hierarchy.

Some references with various points of view:

*Rogers, H. jun.*, Theory of recursive functions and effective computability, Maidenhead, Berksh.: McGraw-Hill Publishing Company, Ltd. 512 p. (1967). [ZBL0183.01401](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0183.01401). (See Ch. 14.1 & 14.7)

*Avigad, Jeremy*, [**Mathematical logic and computation**](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108778756), Cambridge: Cambridge University Press (ISBN 978-1-108-47875-5/hbk; 978-1-108-77875-6/ebook). xii, 513 p. (2023). [ZBL1524.03001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1524.03001). (See Ch. 10.2)

*Simpson, Stephen G.*, Subsystems of second order arithmetic, Perspectives in Mathematical Logic. Berlin: Springer. xiv, 444 p. (1999). [ZBL0909.03048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0909.03048). (See Ch. I.7 - Definition I.7.8)

*Schwichtenberg, Helmut; Wainer, Stanley S.*, [**Proofs and computations**](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139031905), Perspectives in Logic. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press; Urbana, IL: Association for Symbolic Logic (ASL) (ISBN 978-0-521-51769-0/hbk; 978-1-139-03190-5/ebook). xiii, 465 p. (2012). [ZBL1294.03006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1294.03006). (See Ch. 2.6, 3.1 & the definition on p.151)

Comment: $g_y(x)=0$ is a computable relation, so is $\Sigma_1,$ which is all you need for $G$ to be $\Pi_2.$

Comment: I’m saying even if you use the bounded quantifier definition, computable relations (say, implemented by the beta function) are syntactically $\Sigma_1$ so a $\forall\exists$ of one is syntactically $\Pi_2$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see, thank you. Let me see if I understand you. For example, a sentence like $\phi:=\forall x\,(0+x=x)$ is $\Pi_{1}$ because $\theta:=(0+x=x)$ is $\Sigma_{0}$ ($=\Pi_{0}=\Delta_{0}$). And if I wanted to prove $\phi$ in $I\Sigma_{0}$ I would use $I\Sigma_{0}$-induction on $\theta$. Am I correct? In any case, is there a reference you may recommend for learning these topics?

Comment: you didn’t say anything incorrect there but I fail to see how it has anything to do with what I said. I don’t have anything in particular… intro books on computability theory tend to have treatments of arithmetical hierarchy, as do the “intro to godel’s theorem” variety

Comment: My point was just this: if $\psi$ is $\Sigma_1,$ then $\forall x\exists y \;\psi$ is $\Pi_2$, by definition. In your post you're worried that you can't show $\psi$ is $\Delta_0$... it isn't (under the bounded quantifiers only definition), but it doesn't need to be... all it needs to be is $\Sigma_1.$

Answer (score 1):

"Only bounded quantifiers" should be understood as "all quantifiers are bounded", so a formula with no quantifiers at all would qualify vacuously as having "only bounded quantifiers".

So $x = y+1$ would have "only bounded quantifiers". It is $\Pi_0$ (and $\Sigma_0$).

Thus $\theta := \exists y (x = y + 1)$ would be $\Sigma_1$.

Now, in the logically equivalent formula $\theta' := \exists y\,(y<x\wedge x=y+1)$, the quantifier on $y$ is bounded.  Thus $\theta'$ is $\Sigma_0$ (and $\Pi_0$).

Since $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are logically equivalent, then $\theta$ is also $\Sigma_0$ and $\Pi_0$.

Usually we are interested in the least $n$ which classifies a formula as either $\Sigma_n$ or $\Pi_n$.

Comment: The way I learned that, but I'm aware that the notation differs between sources, is that $\Pi_n$ would be the form in which a formula is written, but $\Pi^0_n$ would be the class "up to equivalence".

Comment: @John Please read the answer again. I made some significant changes since I realized it doesn't really make sense to talk about classifying closed sentences.

Comment: "we don't usually classify closed sentences" I don't think so. Logicians discuss the complexity of sentences (like, the complexity of the continuum hypothesis is $\Sigma^2_1$.)

Comment: @HanulJeon Ok, it seems like I may be somewhat confused, so I deleted the part about closed formulas.

Comment: The possible reason for the confusion is that you reason semantically, but the formula complexity is a syntactic concept.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. This makes sense. Where did you learn it? Is there a particular book or otherwise reference you have in mind?

Comment: @John: Lecture notes when I was TA on a course where this was taught. Unfortunately, these were in Hebrew.